# jQuery date picker does not work after refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using jQuery datepicker. It is okay, when i ran my project in Firefox browser from localhost. After some time, When i refresh Firefox again nothing displayed of the jQuery datepicker.

After i ran it chrome it's okay but refresh again it's gone . But when i ran it from other location(Desktop) except localhost it's work properly
Here is my  .....

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12 date-area-left">
 <label class="date-label" for="username">Choose a Date : <span class="star-icon-choose">*</span></label>
 <div style="width: 280px; font-family: 'Arial'; margin: auto;">
    <div class="some_datepicker" style="display: block"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And here is JS....

```js
        <script type = "text/javscript>
             // Localization

            jQueryDatepicker.day_names_short = {
              1: 'Mon',
              2: 'Tue',
              3: 'Wed',
              4: 'Thu',
              5: 'Fri',
              6: 'Sat',
              7: 'Sun'
            };

            jQueryDatepicker.day_names = {
              1: 'Monday',
              2: 'Tuesday',
              3: 'Wednesday',
              4: 'Thursday',
              5: 'Friday',
              6: 'Saturday',
              7: 'Sunday'
            };

            jQueryDatepicker.month_names = {
              1: 'January',
              2: 'February',
              3: 'March',
              4: 'Apri',
              5: 'May',
              6: 'June',
              7: 'July',
              8: 'Agust',
              9: 'September',
              10: 'October',
              11: 'November',
              12: 'December'
            };

            $(document).ready(function() {
              var $selected = $('.selected');

              $some_datepicker = $('.some_datepicker');

              $some_datepicker.datepicker({
                next_button: '&gt;',
                prev_button: '&lt;'
              });

              $some_datepicker.setStartDate({
                year: 2015,
                // jquery.datepicker accepts first month as 1
                // (built-in Date() class accepts first month as 0)
                month: 1,
                day: 3
              });

              $some_datepicker.on('date_selected.datepicker', function(event, date) {
                $selected.show().html('Selected date is: ' + date.date.toString());
              });
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: Try to look at the console log of the browsers.

Comment: @Shahidul Islam can you provide working code.?

Comment: Initially it 's working, after refresh it is not working that means nothing displayed. @ Himesh Aadeshara

Comment: You lost a double quotation mark in the first line of your js code.

Answer (score 0):

A page can't be manipulated safely until the `document is "ready."` `jQuery` detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model `(DOM)` is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside `$( window ).load(function()` { ... }) will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //Insert your code here and try. 
});
```